# Is there a way to run git within Powershell?

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, powershell-2.0, msys

Is there a way to run git within Powershell?

I have a Windows 7 box with msysgit.  I'd like to have a single shell to also run all my git commands as well as play around with Powershell scripting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when you run the msysgit installer make sure you choose the option to install git to be able to run from the Windows command prompt.

[image: Installer]

This will add git to your `PATH` variable, which will make it available to PowerShell.

Answer (score 8):

For a better experience try the following links:

- [Git & PowerShell Revisited](http://www.markembling.info/view/git-powershell-revisited)
- [Using Git (and everything else) through PowerShell](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/using-git-and-everything-else-through-powershell/)
- [Displaying GIT Branch on your PowerShell prompt](http://techblogging.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/displaying-git-branch-on-your-powershell-prompt/)
- [Pimp your command-line for git](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/03/19/pimp-your-command-line-for-git/)
- [Using Git with Windows Powershell](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/03/07/using-git-with-windows-powershell/)