# How to use git's "touch" cmd in PowerShell to make .ignore file?

Tags: powershell, git, touch

How can I use the `touch` command to make an ".ignore" file from PowerShell?

I can use the command in the git Bash (MINGW64)

```
me@my_computer MINGW64 ~/stuff (master)
$ touch .gitignore
```

...but it would be great to stay in PowerShell and work around Windows desire to not have filenames which start with a period.  The Bash help/man/info pages do not recognize `touch`.  FWIW, I am following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9XZQO1n_7c) and did some research with the links in the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/125890/is-there-a-way-to-run-git-within-powershell) but have not found an answer.  When I try `touch .gitignore` in PowerShell I get this error msg:

```
PS C:\Users\_user_name_\stuff> touch .gitignore
The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:6
+ touch <<<<  .gitignore
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `new-item .gitignore -itemtype file` seems to work but is kinda clunky to type

Comment: How can I make an alias that accepts the -itemtype? `new-alias -name touch -value new-item -itemtype file` doesn't work...

Comment: Just `new-item .gitignore` works, it assumes you want a file when you're in a hard drive location.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes it does, but it'd be nice to just have two words to type in. I'm looking into how to make a PS function so I can add a 'touch' alias to my profile which presumes a type: file. Thanks.

Comment: How is "new-item .gitignore" and different than "touch .gitignore"?  Since you now know you don't need the "-itemtype", then you should be able to simply alias new-item as "touch". Having said that, "new-item" already has an alias: "ni".  So `ni .gitignore` should work fine for what you're asking, and it's even shorter. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 "ni"ce :) good to know! The only difference is that `ni` or `new-item` require either `-itemtype file` or answering the `Type:` query - just more keystrokes is all. I'm a PS novice, so partly I am just poking at it trying to learn my way around. I think I have a simple function I can use now tho: `function touch_file
{new-item $args[0] -itemtype file}
new-alias -name touch -value touch_file`
and I can just enter `touch .filename`. Added it to my profile and it appears to work! Yay!

Comment: The way you get around Windows' not wanting to start a filename with a period is by adding a second period to the end, in this case name the file `.gitignore.`. Windows will recognize that this means you are sure that you want the name to start with a period, and will create the file as `.gitignore` without the second period.

Comment: @MosheKatz good to know! This works fine but still requires verbosely including `-itemtype file` with the command or answering the Type query when the command is entered without the specification flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code to my .ps1 profile does the trick:
C:\Users\user_name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

```
<#
The following function and alias assignment
are for use with git to create files which
start with a period, e.g. .gitignore
#>
function touch_file
{new-item $args[0] -itemtype file}
new-alias -name touch -value touch_file
```

And now I can enter `touch .gitignore` into the PowerShell prompt and not have Windows balk at my filename starting with a period or asking me to tell what type of object it is making:

```
PS C:\Users\user_name> touch .gitignore
    Directory: C:\Users\user_name
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         8/16/2016  11:41 PM          0 .gitignore
```

One step closer to getting my lappy to respond adequately to "Do what I want!" :)